# Calculate the surface integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Let $T$ be the portion of the surface $x^2= y^2 + z^2$ lying between the planes $x= 0$ and $x= 2$ and above the plane $z=0$. Calculate the surface integral

$$\iint_T (2 + x^2 y^2)\ \mathrm{d}S $$
i.e mass of surface $T$ if its density is $2 + x^2y^2$.

I don't know which formula I should use in this case. Thanks all!

Comment: I thought about switching it to polar coordinates, with x = r, 0 < x < 2 and use the A(S)= sqrt [1 + (dx/dz)^2 + (dx/dy)^2 ] but something doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

You could find a parametrization of the cone, such as
\begin{align}
x &= r \\
y &= r\cos{t} \\
z &= r\sin{t}
\end{align}
In other words, you have found a function $\varphi(r,\,t)$ wich is:
$$ \varphi(r,\,t) = (r,\, r\cos(t),\, r\sin(t)) $$

Then, you can solve the first type surface integral using:
$$ \renewcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}} $$
$$ \iint_M f(x,\,y,\,z)\d S = \iint_U f\left(\varphi\left(r,\,t\right)\right)\cdot\|\varphi_r\times\varphi_t\|\d (r,\,t)$$

Where $U$ are the boundaries of your new parametrization, in other words, you have:

\begin{align}
\varphi_r &= (1,\, \cos(t),\, \sin(t)) \\
\varphi_u &= (0, -r\sin(t),\, r\cos(t)) \\
\|\varphi_r\times\varphi_t\| &= \sqrt{2}r
\end{align}

And the field $f$ evaluated in $\varphi$ is
$$ f(\varphi(r,\,t)) = 2 + r^4\cos^2(t) $$

Now, the last thing you need are the new boundaries, wich are:
\begin{align}
r &\in [0,\,2] \\
t &\in [0, \pi]
\end{align}

So in the end, you only need to find the answer for:
$$ \sqrt{2} \int_0^\pi\int_0^2 2r + r^5\cos^2(t) \d r\d t $$